# Create a new column in Pandas Dataframe, extracting domain from URI

Tags: python, pandas

The code I wrote for this task works just fine, but I know its not the most pythonic so I'm looking for some advice.  I have a dataframe of log files and one of the columns has a full URL (hostname + path etc).  I wrote this code to extract the domain:

```
    # Generate domain column from uri
    import uritools  
    domain = [] 
    for value in df['uri']: 
        try:
            nuri = [uritools.urisplit(value).authority if uritools.isuri(value) else value]
            domain.append(nuri) 
        except:
            domain.append(None)
    df['domain'] = domain
```

As I say, this works, but its ugly.  The output is fine, but when I try to trim it up to a one liner, it doesn't work.  Here's what I tried:

```
df['domain'] = [uritools.urisplit(df.uri).authority if uritools.isuri(df.uri) else df.uri]
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

How can I improve this to be more appropriate?

Comment: For one thing, it looks like you're missing "for" in your list comprehension at the bottom, so it's not iterating through anything, it's just passing the entire dataframe to the uritools.isuri() function. Try inserting that and see if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide an iterable for a list comprehension

```
df['domain'] = [uritools.urisplit(uri).authority if uritools.isuri(uri) else uri for uri in df.uri]
```

Notice `df.uri` only comes up at the end of the line